# Windows phone 8.1 Whatsap works on wifi only

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp

After updatinfg to windows phone 8.1, whatsap works only through wi-fi. It cannot work through mobile data connection. How can I make it to work through mobile data?

Comment: Do other apps which use data work correctly?

Comment: Yes. Other apps are perfectly fine. Only whatsapp remains offline even though mobile data is enabled

Comment: Have you reinstalled the app?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only two solutions

1) Please remove the whatsapp app and reinstall it.

2) Remove the data limit in data sense app then try it out

If even restoring your phone doesn't work out its because your network operator/provider must have blocked the whatsapp data (It is because they want you to spend your hard earned money on the outdated SMS)